# How to test a function inside a functional component with Jest in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following code in a javascript file in react native

```
const LoseView = () => {

const [currentJoke, setCurrentJoke] = useState("");

const fetchJokeApi = async () => {
    // Fetching data from the API
        await fetch("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Miscellaneous,Pun?blacklistFlags=nsfw,religious,political,racist,sexist,explicit&type=single")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => 
            setCurrentJoke(data.joke),
            );
  };

useEffect(() => {
    fetchJokeApi();
 }, [])

return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1,alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text>you lost!, have a lame consolation joke</Text>
        <Text>{currentJoke}</Text>
   </View>
);
}


export {LoseView};
```

I want to test the function saved in the variable `fetchJokeApi`, but I have no idea how specifically test this with jest. Because in the test file, I know I can import LoseView thanks to the export at the end of the script, but how do I access it's inner functions? Should I export the inner functions individually?

Comment: You don't (_can't_) access its inner functions. Test the _behaviour_ instead - in this case, use e.g. MSW to provide an appropriate response without having to wait for the request to go over the network.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the answer! what is e.g. MSW?

Comment: https://mswjs.io/